# Need assistance evaluating the SQL statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am a bit confused evaluating the statement shown below :

```
AND getdate() BETWEEN fti.effectivestart AND ISNULL(fti.effectiveend, '2050-01-01')
```

Whenever I want to get a date range for a column say an employee's `StartDate`, I would do something like this :

```
AND StartDate BETWEEN fti.effectivestart AND ISNULL(fti.effectiveend, '2050-01-01')
```

Can someone help me understand the difference please ?

Thank you.

Comment: What is the actual question and what is not clear to you?

Comment: might as well state what you are after of.. looking at the structure you are actually looking at employee master and jobhistory

Comment: Hi Tim / rhian ,
I am not sure as to how the first statement is being evaluated? I get the second statement , i.e. basically the records for the Start Date column will be returned which fall between the fti.effectivestart AND isnull(fti.effectiveend, '2050-01-01')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only difference between the 2 statements is that one is comparing against the current date (`getdate()`) and the other is comparing against a given date (`StartDate`).

That is, the 1st statement is verifying if the current date of execution (Now) is `between fti.effectivestart AND ISNULL(fti.effectiveend, '2050-01-01')`

while the second will verify the value of your `StartDate` against the condition `between fti.effectivestart AND ISNULL(fti.effectiveend, '2050-01-01')`

Answer (score 0):

Both the statements are returning a record that is valid at a point in time.

The first is evaluated for the current time.  That is what `getdate()` returns.

The second is evaluated for `StartDate`, which might differ for each row.

Is that what you are confused about?

A couple notes:

- `coalesce()` is usually (but not always) preferable to `isnull()` because the former is ANSI standard.
- If your effect and end dates are *dates* (with no time component), then you probably want `cast(getdate() as date)`.
- You need to be careful when using `between` with dates.  I assume the table is set up so this works as expected.

Comment: Hi Gordon Thank you for your response. Yes precisely , so I was just trying to a run a sql statement and I was getting duplicate records returned. My friend suggested me to use the AND getdate() BETWEEN fti.effectivestart AND isnull(fti.effectiveend, '2050-01-01')
But I was not sure as how to evaluate it .

Comment: @JackJames . . . You may be getting duplicate records because `between` is the wrong way to compare dates.  You can ask *another* question with sample data and show sample data that generates duplicates.

Comment: @GordonLinoff "between is the wrong way to compare dates." care to elaborate?

Comment: So the effective start and effective end columns are datetime data type and just not date.
And after using AND getdate() BETWEEN fti.effectivestart AND isnull(fti.effectiveend, '2050-01-01') it gave me the results just fine eliminating the duplicates. I just dont clearly understand the logic . 
For the second statement its clear And StartDate Between fti.effectivestart AND isnull(fti.effectiveend, '2050-01-01') - That basically the records for the Start Date column will be returned which fall between the fti.effectivestart AND isnull(fti.effectiveend, '2050-01-01')

Comment: @Jack James: It seems, if you *really* want to get to the bottom of this you will have to provide some sample data.